# HikariCP Google Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory cloudSqlInstance property not set

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, hikaricp

I wish to connect to Google Cloud SQL using JDBC SocketFactory in a Spring 4 application.

The dependencies in pom.xml are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The applicationContext.xml contains:

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="30000" />

    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">jdbc:postgresql://google/mydb?cloudSqlInstance=projectId:region:instance&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory</prop>
            <prop key="user">postgres</prop>
            <prop key="password">password</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But when I run the application, I get the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cloudSqlInstance
>   property not set. Please specify this property in the JDBC URL or the
>   connection Properties with value in form "project:region:instance"
>           at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:135)

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: The error points out that your JDBC URL’s cloud SQL instance is not written properly. You are supposed to provide an instance connection name which has a general structure of ‘myproject:region:myinstance’. You can find it in your console by navigating to SQL, clicking on the instance you’d like to connect to and looking for the “Connect to this instance” section, where you can copy your instance connection name.

Read the github [readme](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory) if you would like to know more about connecting to a SQL instance.

Comment: @ddworks I'm providing cloudSqlInstance=projectId:region:instance in the URL

Comment: @ddworks As per this line `<prop key="url">jdbc:postgresql://google/mydb?cloudSqlInstance=projectId:region:instance&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory</prop>` it seems the OP is providing the corerct structure. @user5155835 make sure your are substituting  it with the correct values.

Comment: The full  JDBC url shoul look like this: `jdbc:postgresql://google/<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=<POSTGRESQL_USER_NAME>&password=<POSTGRESQL_USER_PASSWORD>`. You can find more info [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#postgres)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would be caused by the use of PGSimpleDatasource. The Postgres datasources filters all connection url properties. The only allowed ones are those found in the following enum:

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/PGProperty.html

You can see the filtering here:

https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/ds/common/BaseDataSource.java#L1276

Since cloudSqlInstance is not on this list it will not be available to the socket factory.

The solution would propabaly be to use another datasource implementation.